# How can we compare more than 2 or multiple arrays in Typescript, Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

I have 4 arrays in which I have to check if any same item is in more than 2 arrays. if it is, then based on a property I have to delete from all others except one.

```
let arrayA = [{id: 1, modifiedOn: 1234}, {id: 2, modifiedOn: 1234}, {id: 3, modifiedOn: 1234}]

let arrayB = [{id: 4, modifiedOn: 1234}, **{id: 2, modifiedOn: 1235}**, {id: 5, modifiedOn: 1234}]

let arrayC = [{id: 6, modifiedOn: 1234}, {id: 7, modifiedOn: 1234},
**{id: 5, modifiedOn: 1235}**]

let arrayD = [**{id: 1, modifiedOn: 1235}**, {id: 8, modifiedOn: 1234}, {id: 9, modifiedOn: 1234}]
```

As you can see from above, **id 2, id 5 and id 1** are in more than 1 array, which ever items **modifiedOn** is bigger it should stay and other should be delete.

Comment: I wouldn't include Angular & TypeScript in tags, it's not related.

Answer (score 0):

https://codepen.io/vitkarpov/pen/GRpZzqx

```
function buildSearchIndex(arrays) {
  const index = {};

  for (let i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < arrays[i].length; j++) {
      const {id, modifiedOn} = arrays[i][j];
      index[id] = index[id] || {};
      index[id][modifiedOn] = [arrays[i], j];
    }
  }
  return index;
}

function removeDuplicates(...arrays) {
  const searchIndex = buildSearchIndex(arrays);

  Object.keys(searchIndex).forEach((id) => {
    const index = searchIndex[id];
    const modifiedOnRecords = Object.keys(index);

    // skip first, it corresponds to the value with the smallest modifiedOn value
    for (let i = 1; i < modifiedOnRecords.length; i++) {
      const modifiedOn = modifiedOnRecords[i];
      const [arr, j] = index[modifiedOn];
      arr.splice(j, 1);
    }
  });
}

let arrayA = [{id: 1, modifiedOn: 1234}, {id: 2, modifiedOn: 1234}, {id: 3, modifiedOn: 1234}]
let arrayB = [{id: 4, modifiedOn: 1234}, {id: 2, modifiedOn: 1235}, {id: 5, modifiedOn: 1234}]
let arrayC = [{id: 6, modifiedOn: 1234}, {id: 7, modifiedOn: 1234}, {id: 5, modifiedOn: 1235}]
let arrayD = [{id: 1, modifiedOn: 1235}, {id: 8, modifiedOn: 1234}, {id: 9, modifiedOn: 1234}]

removeDuplicates(arrayA, arrayB, arrayC, arrayD);
```

I really liked this problem. It looks like a good candidate for a whiteboard interview, actually :-)